# Help with chapter bibliography and general bibliography in thesis

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, cross-referencing, templates, thesis

I am submitting my PhD thesis and our department requires a separate bibliography for each chapter that contains an article, I have got 4 chapters, the first chapter is a literature review (not an article) which means I do not need to generate a bibliography for it. The university's template of the root file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[PhD,bibsection,english]{ulthese}
 
  \ifxetex\else \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \fi


  \titre{<Titre principal>}
  
  \auteur{<Prénom Nom>}
  \direction{<Prénom Nom>, <directeur ou directrice> de recherche}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter                   

\frontispice                  

\include{resume}               
\include{abstract}             
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents               
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables                   
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures                  
\cleardoublepage

\dedicace{<Dédicace si désiré>}
\cleardoublepage

\epigraphe{<Texte de l'épigraphe>}{<Source ou auteur>}
\cleardoublepage

\include{remerciements}         
\include{avantpropos}           

\mainmatter                     

\include{introduction}         
\include{chapitre1-articles}   
\include{chapitre2-articles}    
\include{conclusion}            

\appendix                       

\include{annexe}               

\end{document}
```

and they suggest having the following in each article chapter:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
```

However, if I only use their code, I cannot generate the references of my first chapter (literature review), and I cannot generate the overall bibliography at the end of the document. If I add \bibliographystyle{plainnat} and \bibliography{references} to the root file as follows:

```
\documentclass[PhD,bibsection,english]{ulthese}
 
  \ifxetex\else \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \fi

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

  \titre{<Titre principal>}
  
  \auteur{<Prénom Nom>}
  \direction{<Prénom Nom>, <directeur ou directrice> de recherche}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter                    

\frontispice                    

\include{resume}                
\include{abstract}              
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents               
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables                  
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures                  
\cleardoublepage

\dedicace{<Dédicace si désiré>}
\cleardoublepage

\epigraphe{<Texte de l'épigraphe>}{<Source ou auteur>}
\cleardoublepage

\include{remerciements}         
\include{avantpropos}           

\mainmatter                     

\include{introduction}          
\include{chapitre1-articles}    
\include{chapitre2-articles}    
\include{conclusion}           

\appendix                      

\include{annexe}                

\bibliography{references}  

\end{document}
```

Then I try to do Bibtex, it shows the following error:

```
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 208 of file Chapter1.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {plainnat}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibdata command---line 56 of file PhD_thesis_aziez_111187664.aux
 : \bibdata
 :         {references}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: references.bib
(There were 2 error messages)
```

In addition, the references in my first chapter (literature review) are all question marks "?", and the overall bibliography appears as a subsection of the conclusion as follows:
[image]

I tried some solutions including: chapterbib and bibunits but without any success. I hope that you can help me.

Comment: As far as I understand `ulthese` uses `chapterbib`, when using `chapterbib` with an overall bibliography the `Illegal, another \bibstyle command` error is expected (see "7 Overall bibliography" of the `chapterbib` documenation) and shouldn't cause errors. Could you confirm exactly what `bibtex` calls you are making? Are you able to construct a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)? There's probably something causing an issue in chapter 1 (does `bibtex chap1` give any errors?)

Comment: For the final bibliography, try ` \sectionbib{\chapter*}{chapter}` just before the final `\bibliography`